# Invalid address. It does not belong to any of this network's subnets

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ipv4, subnet

Whenever I run:

```
     docker-compose -f net.yaml up -d
```

I get the following errors:

```
     Creating network "twisted_static-network" with the default driver.
     Creating server ... error

     ERROR: for server  Cannot start service tcp_server: Invalid address 192.168.1.1: It 
     does not belong to any of this network's subnets

     ERROR: for tcp_server  Cannot start service tcp_server: Invalid address 
     192.168.1.1: It does not belong to any of this network's subnets
     ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I have tried:

1. To `prune` the docker network,
2. Deleted & re-installed docker,
3. Changed the ipv4 address.

But the problem never change.

#### net.yaml

```
    version: '3'

    services:
      tcp_server:
        image: twisted_tcp:1.0
        container_name: server
        environment:
          - LOCAL_IP=192.168.1.1
        ports:
          - 5679:5678
        privileged: true
        volumes:
          - ./twisted_server.py:/run/twisted_server.py 
        command: >
            bash -c pip3 install twisted
            && "python3 twisted_server.py"
        networks:
          static-network:
            ipv4_address: 192.168.1.1

      tcp_client:
        image: twisted_tcp:1.0    
        depends_on:
          - tcp_server
        container_name: client
        environment:
          - LOCAL_IP=192.168.1.2
        ports:
          - 5680:5678
        privileged: true
        volumes:
          - ./twisted_client.py:/run/twisted_client.py
        command: >
          bash -c pip3 install twisted
                  && "python3 twisted_client.py"
        networks:
          static-network:
            ipv4_address: 192.168.1.2


    networks:
      static-network:
        ipam:
          config:
            - subnet: 192.168.0.0/24
              gateway: 192.168.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Always try to give IP from the assigned network. it works fine for me check below

My Network is

```
# docker network create --subnet 198.168.10.0/24 --driver bridge prod
341a36aaf31d71d5fdf2721c94a429a70fd5ae60f083d6b7a72f71916393534f
```

So,from above command it's clear we need to assign the IP from our network that is `198.168.10.0/24`

```
# docker run -d --name=web10 --network prod --ip 198.168.10.10 nginx
ed8a251ad65f5ac9576d613bb66d33e47ffbbca8cee7ef7cb8681bedb1ea7c81
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work with 192.168.1.0/24 as well. The problem was that  IP assignment in the config was outside the subnet range.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solved!

The issue ended up being the `-subnet` in the `net.yaml`

1. I changed this: `-subnet: 192.168.0.0/24`
2. To this: `-subnet: 192.168.0.0/16`

Then it works!